# Gauss map of a surface and symmetry of the surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

This question is motivated by Problem 10.2 of "Geometry from a Differentiable Viewpoint" by McCleary.

**Question**: Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular orientable surface, $N:S\longrightarrow\mathbb{S}^2$ be the corresponding Gauss map, and $\rho:\mathbb{R}^3\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3\in O(3)$ be an orthogonal linear transformation such that $\rho(S)=S$ (in other words, the surface $S$ is symmetric with respect to the rigid motion $\rho$).

Then, can we say $N\circ\rho\vert_S=\rho\vert_{\mathbb{S}^2}\circ N$?

In other words, I am wondering if the surface is symmetric, then the corresponding Gauss map is also symmetric. Intuitively I think it must be true, but I could not construct a rigorous proof. This kind of question must be classical, is there any reference dealing with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Gauss map is equivariant with respect to rigid motions in your sense, provided we're careful with orientation.

If $p$ is a point of $S$, and if $u$ and $v$ comprise a basis of the tangent plane $T_{p}S$ such that $N(p) = u \times v$, then $\rho(u)$ and $\rho(v)$ comprise a basis for the tangent plane $T_{\rho(p)}S$ because $S$ is invariant under $\rho$. Consequently,
$$
\rho(N(p)) = \rho (u \times v) = \det(\rho)\rho(u) \times \rho(v)
$$
is a unit vector orthogonal to $T_{\rho(p)}S$. Since $S$ is oriented and the ordered triple $(\det(\rho)\rho(u), \rho(v), N(\rho(p)))$ has the same orientation as $(u, v, N(p))$, we have
$$
\rho(N(p)) = N(\rho(p)).
$$

Comment: Nice, thank you for the answer!